# How to use --outDir TypeScript compilerOptions

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, aurelia

I'm facing an issue where the compiler complains about the following: Cannot write file 'path/file.json' because it would overwrite input file. I did some digging and most solutions suggest to use outDir to fix it. That solutions works fine but I'm not sure what folder to pass to it. Right now I have it set up as follows and the compiler stopped complaining:

```js
outDir: "path/file.json",
```

I'm not too sure if that's a good idea because I'm basically passing it itself. The Json is just an object that I'm reading from and I'm using an Aurelia project. Any tips or information will be greatly appreciated.

[image: My folder structure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you don't want this json file to be compiled?  Maybe just add it to the "exclude" glob in your tsconfig.json so tsc doesn't process it?

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

I usually split mine into
src/
dist/

Then my tsconfig would have something like

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do. I tried the "exclude" but the error was still there. Any other suggestions?

Comment: That's hard to say without a better understanding of you project structure etc.

Comment: what does outDir really do though? can you explain how it works?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html  

`outDir -  Redirect output structure to the directory`  

Instead of compiling ts|tsx into a js file in the same directory it will produce the resulting files in the specified directory.

Comment: do you know what happens if I give it a directory that does not exist?

Comment: I think it would create it.  Should be easy enough to test

Comment: I don't see any folders created even after trying a few times. The file that's causing an issue is a JSON so maybe that's why? Sorry I have so many questions, I'm worried about going to production later on

Comment: Can you share some of your project?  Package.json, tsconfig or the command you are using when you get the error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184339/discussion-between-sbattoh-and-green-reign).

Comment: I posted a new message in the chat, weird how it doesn't notify you