# Typescript development environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, tsconfig

I am starting with typescript. I started with an empty folder and ran these commands to set up my typescript development.

```
  npm init 
  npm install typescript
  npm install @types/node
```

then i made a tsconfig file

```
npx tsc --init
```

I tried changing my output dir in tsconfig.json like `"outDir": "./dist"`,

But that doesn't seem to work. the transpiled file is still coming into the src folder.
I have a folder structure like :

```
                   root
                   |_ node_modules
                   |_ src
                     |_ index.ts
                   |_ dist
                   |_package.json
                   |_tsconfig.json
                   |_package-lock.json
```

Here is the tsconfig.json file

```
"compilerOptions": {
               "target": "es5",                          
               "module": "commonjs",
               "outDir": "./dist",                        
               "rootDir": "./src",    
               "strict": true,
               "esModuleInterop": true, 
               "skipLibCheck": true,                         
               "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use --outDir TypeScript compilerOptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53483199/how-to-use-outdir-typescript-compileroptions)

Comment: @RandyCasburn that answers a totally different scenario. I have my tsconfig file not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `tsc`. You just specify one file. TypeScript doesn't worry about making it work as a module by itself as you don't have a need for modules with just one file.
Oh also, from the cli reference:

> Transpile just the index.ts with the compiler defaults `tsc index.ts`

Answer (score 0):

> the transpiled file is still coming into the src folder.

You also need to set a rootDir. In your case it should be `"rootDir": "src"`.

Comment: I tried that doesn't help. It seems like somehow it is not picking up tsoncfig file.

Comment: The default is the folder the `tsconfig` is in.